# Load another JS file in JS and stop current

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was asking myself if there is a way to load a JS file in a JS file and stop the current JS

Example; Loading from index.html to Fake.js and Fake.js has a bunch of fake coding, and one line what he actually most do, loading Real.js.

This is for to keep my JS file not easy to copy by people who just go to http://example.com/Fake.js

Comment: Sounds like it should work. I personally don't see any reason to do it, but it would work. Here you go: [`[javascript] dynamically load file`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+dynamically+load+file)

Comment: What you're after is code obfuscation. You have a few options: the [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is one of them; [javascript obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com) is another. You can google for others.

Comment: What you're currently after will not prevent people from viewing your `real.js` file, as they can always just view it within their browser's console.

Comment: @Luxelin: You might want to add that obfuscation doesn't do that either.

Comment: @FelixKling This is true, as it can always be backwards engineered. It's an extra step, though, and obfuscation at least minimizes your file (if you use the closure compiler, iirc).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, and you can put your js in css file and still load it like this. You can substitute fetch with vanilla ajax.

```
fetch('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js').then(function(data){
    return data.text();
}).then(function(data) {
    eval(data);
});
```